# 途中で実行に失敗しても必ず特定タスクを実行したい

Tags: ansible

普段停止中のサーバーを自動起動してレシピ実行後に停止に戻したいです

role や pretasks がうまく使えなかったのでプレイブックごとまとめて

```
- import_playbook: playbooks/start-instances.yml
- import_playbook: <やりたいレシピ>
- import_playbook: playbooks/stop-instances.yml
```

このように書いてみたのですがレシピが途中で失敗してしまうと停止処理が行われず
手動で停止しなければいけません

ignore_errors というオプションもタスクレベルにしか使えず
やりたいレシピの中に書くのはおかしい気がするのですが
import_playbook の中でエラーが出ても処理を止めない方法ってありますか？

タスクレベルの処理にできないのは start-instances.yml, stop_instances は対象インスタンスの外部(ansible 実行サーバー)から AWS コマンドを叩いて起動するものでレシピ実行ホストが異なるからです

ansible-playbook 2.9.4 です

Answer (score 2):

[block/rescue](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) が使えると思います。

```
- block:
    - import_playbook: playbooks/start-instances.yml
    - import_playbook: <やりたいレシピ>

  rescue:
    - import_playbook: playbooks/stop-instances.yml
```

block内の処理がエラーになるとrescue内の処理が実行されます。

Comment: 上の３行だけでも syntax error になります。block は tasks の外の play コンテキストにもかけるのでしょうか